# ArcGIS Pro - ERROR 010167: Could not open workspace <undefined>

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, extract-by-mask, workspace

I'm trying to run the Extract by Mask tool in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 to extract areas of a raster overlain by a polygon layer. I keep getting:

> ERROR 010167: Could not open workspace .

I have tried creating a new arc project and also running the tool from my files in an entirely new location, but I keep getting the same error. Full error details pasted below.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than in a picture.

Comment: A paste of the "Copy as Python snippet..." from the Results log could help as well.

Comment: Looks like the path name to the output or input is wrong? But without seeing how you ran the tool it is very difficult to answer. Are you for example using in-memory workspaces? If so some tools do not work with those.